# How to set value for nth.child numeric text box input field

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I want to know how to set value for nth-child numeric text input field. I tried this inside the kendo grid save event as below.

```
e.container.closest("tr").children(':nth-child(10)').val(8);
```

how can I do this?

Comment: what happens with current code

Comment: din't change value :( nothing happened

Comment: add html mark up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the input is inside of a table cell, right?. If that's the case, you could use `eq()` function...

```
e.container.closest("tr").children('td').eq(9).find('input').val(8);
```

NOTE: As @Taufik and @guradio pointed, the index in `eq()` starts in 0 while in `nth-child` starts in '1'.

I hope it helps

Comment: it would be different, because `.eq()` index starts from 0, while `:nth-child()` normally start from 1

Comment: this will wrong because eq starts at index 0 so you should use 9

Comment: You're totally right! Answer edited and comments upvoted. Thanks!